# Repackage as ".application" instead of ".exe" Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

HI in visual studio 2012 and was wondering how do I deploy/repackage as ".application"?

Is this the same process as "Publish" in the build drop down where I publish to a location?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you are looking for ClickOnce which is the Publish button. ClickOnce deploys using the .application file. Google ClickOnce to get tons of info.